# How to configure R to store dot files in central directory

Tags: r, dotfiles

I'd like to store my `R` dotfiles in one central directory, similar to how one can store backups and swapfiles using `vim` by including

```
set backupdir=$HOME/.vim/backups//
```

in one's `.vimrc`.

My reasoning is that I sometimes want to run* `R` to inspect data files in directories where I’d like to be able to count on *every* file in the directory being data. The result is that if I accidentally save my workspace, I have to remember to delete `.Rhistory` etc. afterwards. I was hoping there would be some way to configure `R` so that all of the dot files are saved in `~/R/workspace_images/` or something like that.

*: I run `R` from the command line, not RStudio, although I don't think that should make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming you are on linux, you may set some environment variables to control where and how many lines are saved:

> The (readline on Unix-alikes) history mechanism is controlled by two environment variables: `R_HISTSIZE` controls the number of lines that are saved (default 512), and `R_HISTFILE` (default ‘`.Rhistory`’) sets the filename used for the loading/saving of history if requested at the beginning/end of a session (but not the default for loadhistory/savehistory). There is no limit on the number of lines of history retained during a session, so setting `R_HISTSIZE` to a large value has no penalty unless a large file is actually generated.

from [?utils::savehistory](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/utils/html/savehistory.html)